# Unit testing of a plugin

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

> **@edit**
> It has already been solved

How would the unit test of this plugin be?

```
public function afterPrepare(uiMassAction $subject, $result)
{
    $roleName = $this->adminSession->getUser()->getRole()->getRoleName();

    if ($roleName !== self::ROLE_ADMIN) {
        $subject->setData('config', []);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

**adminSession** has already been mocked, but I can't call **getUser()**, **getRole()** and **geRoleName()**.

```
protected function setup(): void
{
    $this->adminSession       = $this->createMock(Session::class);
    $this->uiMassAction       = $this->createMock(uiMassAction::class);

    $objectManager = new \Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager($this);
    $this->class   = $objectManager->getObject(MassAction::class, [
        'adminSession' => $this->adminSession
    ]);
}
```

I'm learning test unit, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Create user object and role and have the mocked admin session return it. Sample untested code:

```
$user = $this->objectManager->getObject(User::class, []);
$adminSession = $this->createMock(Session::class);
$adminSession->method('__call')->with('getUser')->willReturn($user);
                
$role = $this->objectManager->getObject(Role::class, []);
$role->setRoleId(1)->setRoleName('Administrators');
$user->setId(1)->setUserId(1);
$user->setRole($role);
```